# How do I modify a CSS value after the DOM is created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website and the layout is a bit lazy. I found now that because of clearfix, there is a `div` that its height may be resized if the user triggers it.

My question is, is there a simple way to say that one value of the CSS can't change whenever anything happens, something like:

```
color:black !IMPOSSIBLETOCHANGE
```

Comment: It depends on selector specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Don't use floats.

Comment: There is no such thing that blocks a css value. You can do some hacks like using an animation with the `forwards` keyword if the property is animatable [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/up5271ar/), but still, you should consider including a minimal, complete and verifiable example to get better answers and solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you were close enough that you probably knew about this already:

`color: black !important;`

The only way to override an `!important` style is to make another `!important` style of higher priority (like putting it inline on the `style=` attribute).

Comment: I cant fix the problem with !important. If i change the height of a div that is clearing both and it is next to the div that i dont want it to change, it will change with !important.

Comment: I need a thing that "blocks" the value

Comment: `max-height: [number]px;` with `overflow: hidden;` might do the trick. Without seeing your code we can't help any further.

Answer (score 0):

Use $(document).ready() and change color which will not effect your layout otherwise use color with transparent. 
Like

$("#div").css('color','transparent');

Comment: That probably won't work unless you spell `transparent` correctly. Anyway, whatever it is the OP is trying to do, I think he wants to do it in CSS.